# Can an ordinal be limit of a smaller set of ordinals?

Tags: set-theory, order-theory

The Wikpedia article [Regular cardinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_cardinal) contains the following weird sentence:

> An infinite ordinal $\alpha$ is regular if and only if it is a limit ordinal which is not the limit of a set of smaller ordinals which set has order type less than $\alpha$.

I'm confused by the double-which grammar and I'm not sure if I understand the statement at all. If an ordinal is the limit of a set (like $\omega$ is the limit of the set of finite ordinals), how can this set be smaller then the ordinal itself? I thought the ordinal *is* the set.

And is there even a difference between "is smaller" and "has order type less than"?

Comment: The set of ordinals in question is not necessarily an interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the example in the article : $\omega + \omega$ is the limit of $\omega+n$ with $n$ finite ordinal.

So $\omega + \omega$ is the limit of the set $S = \{ \omega + n\,|\, n\in \omega\}$, and $S$ is indeed smaller than $\omega+\omega$ since $S\simeq \omega$ as an ordered set.

In general if $\alpha$ is the limit of a set $S$ of ordinals, then $S$ must be well-ordered, so $S\simeq \beta$ for some ordinal $\beta$. The definition you highlighted says that if $\alpha$ is regular, you can never take $S\subset \alpha$ and $\beta<\alpha$.

---

Of course this is in some sense optimal because for any $\alpha$, you can always take both $S = \alpha$ (but in this case $S\not\subset \alpha$), and $S = \{\alpha\}$ (but then $\beta = 1$).

Comment: I guess reading everything first before complaining that I don't understand it would have helped! Thanks for the concise explanation.

Answer (score 5):

Let me start with your last question.

There is an important difference between *is smaller than* and *has order type less than*. Two well-orders of different types can have the same cardinality. For example, $\omega$ has smaller order type than $\omega+1$, but both of these sets are countably infinite, so neither is smaller than the other. It’s true that if $\langle A,\le\rangle$ and $\langle B,\preceq\rangle$ are well-orders, and $|A|<|B|$, then the order type of $\langle A,\le\rangle$ is necessarily less than that of $\langle B,\preceq\rangle$, but the reverse implication is false in general.

Now consider the cardinal $\omega_\omega$. It’s a cardinal because if the ordinal $\alpha$ is less than $\omega_\omega$, then $|\alpha|<|\omega_\omega|$, i.e., because it has greater cardinality than any smaller ordinal. Since $\omega=\omega_0<\omega_\omega$, $\omega_\omega$ is clearly an uncountable cardinal. (It is in fact the $\omega$-th uncountable cardinal.) But $\omega_\omega$ is the limit of the sequence $\langle\omega_n:n\in\omega\rangle$. This increasing sequence has order type $\omega$:

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
0&1&2&3&4&\ldots&n&\ldots\\
\omega_0&\omega_1&\omega_2&\omega_3&\omega_4&\ldots&\omega_n&\ldots
\end{array}$$

Thus, $\omega_\omega$ is the limit of a sequence of smaller ordinals (in fact cardinals) that has order type $\omega$, an order type that is less than $\omega_\omega$. This is precisely what it means to say that $\omega_\omega$ is **not** regular (and hence is singular).

Now consider the cardinal $\omega_1$. The order types less than $\omega_1$ are precisely the order types of the ordinals less than $\omega_1$. Suppose that $\alpha$ is an ordinal less than $\omega_1$ and $\langle\beta_\xi:\xi<\alpha\rangle$ is an $\alpha$-sequence of ordinals smaller than $\omega_1$. If $\beta$ is the limit of this sequence, then

$$\beta=\sup_{\xi<\alpha}\beta_\xi=\bigcup_{\xi<\alpha}\beta_\xi\;;$$

$\alpha$ is countable, being less than $\omega_1$, as is each of the sets $\beta_\xi$, so $\beta$ is the union of countably many countable sets and must therefore be countable. In particular, $\beta<\omega_1$. Thus, $\omega_1$ is not the limit of a set $S$ of smaller ordinals such that the order type of $S$ is less then $\omega_1$. That’s exactly what it means to say that $\omega_1$ is regular.

Comment: Wow, I didn't expect this! I don't want to unaccept the previous answer as it answered my main question satisfactorily but this explanation really is amazing. You mentioned that $\omega_\omega$ is a cardinal because all ordinals below have smaller cardinality. Isn't this the definition of an initial ordinal? Is "cardinal" and "initial ordinal" the same, or does every cardinal correspond to an initital ordinal? This might be out of scope here, though …

Comment: @akkarin: Yes, that’s the definition of an initial ordinal. Every well-orderable cardinal corresponds to an initial ordinal, and it’s convenient to identify the initial ordinals with the (well-orderable) cardinals; these are sometimes called von Neumann cardinals. (In the absence of the axiom of choice there can be sets that are not well-orderable; their cardinalities are *not* initial ordinals.)

Answer (score 2):

First, the only regular ordinals are cardinals. Not every cardinal is regular. The first singular (non-regular) cardinal is $\aleph_{\omega}$:
$$\begin{align}
\aleph_{\omega} & = \sup_{\alpha < {\aleph_{\omega}}} \alpha \\
&= \bigcup_{\alpha < {\aleph_{\omega}}} \alpha \\
&= \bigcup_{n < \omega} \aleph_{n} \\
\end{align}$$
(The "limit" of a set of ordinals is their supremum, which happens to be the union of the set.) $\aleph_{\omega}$ the union of the set $S = \{\aleph_n\mid\ n < \omega\}$ which consists of cardinals smaller than $\aleph_{\omega}$ and which is of a smaller size: $\lvert S \rvert = \omega = \aleph_0$. $S$ is not all of $\aleph_{\omega}$, but it's an unbounded subset of $\aleph_{\omega}$, so its union equals $\aleph_{\omega}$.